# Hide one div and show another div every minute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this question has been asked before, but mine is a bit different and I couldn't find the solution myself. I have 2 divs: `container` and `container2`. `container2` is hidden by default, so I want that every 60 seconds, `container` gets hidden and `container2` gets displayed. I have worked around some of the code, and I believe I got close to the solution, but I didn't quite get it, here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('container2').style.display = 'flex';
    document.getElementById('container').style.display = 'none';
}, 60000);
};
```

---

```
#container {
    display: flex;
}

#container2 {
    display: none;

}
```

Right now, `container` is displayed when the website loads, then after 60 seconds, `container2` is displayed, but it doesn't go back to displaying `container` after 60 seconds. I understand why this is not working, I'm just not sure how to fix it. I left a small code snippet to demonstrate what I mean (I changed the time from 1 minute to 5 seconds for demonstration purposes)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('container2').style.display = 'flex';
    document.getElementById('container').style.display = 'none';
}, 5000); // Changed the time from a minute to 5 seconds for this demonstration

};
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #343E59;
  }

#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

#container2 {
    display: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

.titles {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <!--- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Redmine Monitor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    Container
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
    Container2
    </div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Comment: You are setting the same value for the CSS properties every X seconds, which means the elements are never toggled on/off.

Comment: @Terry yes, I am aware of what I'm doing. I know why it doesn't work, it was just the direction I was taking, as I thought maybe I was on the right path, so I wanted to show it. I am a coding student and fairly new to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic if statement solves this.

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('container2').style.display == "flex") {
            document.getElementById('container2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('container').style.display = "flex";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('container2').style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementById('container').style.display = "none";
        }
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not toggling

Use a class

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container2'), container2 = document.getElementById('container');
  setInterval(function() {
    container.classList.toggle("hide")
    container2.classList.toggle("hide")
  }, 1000); 
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #343E59;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

#container2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.titles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.hide { display: none !important; }
```

```html
  <div id="container">
    Container
  </div>
  <div id="container2" class="hide">
    Container2
  </div>
```

Comment: Just wanna note that using `!important` is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: It is however for some reason necessary here since without it, it does not work as expected. Freel free to explain me why I need important and what a better way would be

Answer (score 0):

change the function to:

```
setInterval(function() {
  const c1 = document.getElementById('container');
  const c2 = document.getElementById('container2');

  [c1, c2].forEach(el => {
    el.style.display = el.style.display === 'flex' ? 'none' : 'flex';
  })
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Does this work if flex is not inline?

Answer (score 0):

You have to toggle the display based on the current display of the `container` and `container2` and also you have to set the initial displays either inline or here in javascript otherwise it won't return the `c.style.display` property.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const c = document.getElementById('container');
  const c2= document.getElementById('container2');
  c.style.display = 'flex';
  c2.style.display = 'none';
  setInterval(function() {
      c.style.display = c.style.display === 'none' ? 'flex' : 'none';
      c2.style.display = c2.style.display === 'none' ? 'flex' : 'none';
  }, 5000); // Changed the time from a minute to 5 seconds for this demonstration

};
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #343E59;
  }

#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

#container2 {
    display: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

.titles {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <!--- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Redmine Monitor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    Container
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
    Container2
    </div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to set the second container to `hidden`. You can then use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to pick up the containers, and then iterate over them to toggle them on and off. (I've used `setTimeout` here as I find it more intuitive.)

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('div');

function loop() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    containers.forEach(container => {
      container.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });
    loop();
  }, 1000);
}

loop();
```

```css
div { display: flex; }
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div>One</div>
<div class="hidden">Two</div>
```